# 2015 MacBook Pro screen flickers until HDMI plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've got a 2015 MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra. The display flickers different colours and is basically unusable until I plug in an external monitor to the HDMI port - then both displays work perfectly.

The symptoms are pretty specific but I haven't been able to find a solution online.

Comment: Does your MacBook Pro have a discrete GPU as well as integrated graphics? I believe the integrated graphics is by default used without an external monitor, and the MacBook will switch to the discrete GPU with an external monitor. You could reconfigure this however.

Comment: Integrated graphics. It persisted after resetting the SMC, PRAM, and reinstalling macOS. I know this isn't a solution for everybody but after installing Fedora it all works fine.